# Is it possible to use some kind of auction algorithm to determine payment percentages?

Tags: economics, auction-theory

Me and my friends decided to rent a 3-bedroom apartment together to save money. The rooms have different areas and we all probably value those areas differently. Rent per month for the whole apartment is fixed. Is there an algorithm to determine who pays how much for his room?

So, there is an apartment with rent per month $x$. It has some common areas and 3 rooms with areas $\alpha x$, $\beta x$, $\gamma x$: $\alpha + \beta + \gamma < 1$. There are Alice, Bob, Jane and Joe. Jane and Joe will live in the same room. Everyone wants his room to have the biggest area but they also want to pay less.

Comment: You can use ratio of area to determine who pays how much.

Comment: That was my first idea, but it's far from perfect. Area of common rooms creates value too.

Comment: You have to give more details so that others can give solutions.

Comment: Added more information.

Comment: **Hint:** Use Sperner's Lemma.

Comment: More helpfully, try reading [this](https://www.nytimes.com/2014/04/29/science/to-divide-the-rent-start-with-a-triangle.html).

Comment: @TheoreticalEconomist that seems very useful, thanks a lot